# Method chaining a get function to return specific $this properties

Tags: php, api, class, methods, chaining

I want to be able to use an object like below, to retrieve new orders and new invoices. I feel like it is most readable, but I am having trouble writing the PHP class to work this way.

```
$amazon = new Amazon();
$amazon->orders('New')->get();
$amazon->invoices('New')->get();
```

In my PHP class, how would my get() method be able to distinguish whether to return orders or invoices?

```
<?php

namespace App\Vendors;

class Amazon
{
    private $api_key;
    public $orders;
    public $invoices;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->api_key = config('api.key.amazon');
    }

    public function orders($status = null)
    {
        $this->orders = 'orders123';

        return $this;
    }

    public function invoices($status = null)
    {
        $this->invoices = 'invoices123';

        return $this;
    }

    public function get()
    {
        // what is the best way to return order or invoice property
        // when method is chained?
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you show your class here you are trying to implement?

Comment: @PubuduJayawardana added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of ways, if you want it dynamic and don't do any logic in the methods, use something like [`__call`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call)

```
<?php
class Amazon {
    public $type;
    public $method;

    public function get()
    {
        // do logic
        // ...

        return 'Fetching: '.$this->method.' ['.$this->type.']';
    }

    public function __call($method, $type)
    {
        $this->method = $method;
        $this->type = $type[0];

        return $this;
    }

}

$amazon = new Amazon();

echo $amazon->orders('New')->get();
echo $amazon->invoices('New')->get();
```

If you want to do logic in the methods, do something like:

```
<?php
class Amazon {
    public $type;
    public $method;

    public function get()
    {
        return 'Fetching: '.$this->method.' ['.$this->type.']';
    }

    public function orders($type)
    {
        $this->method = 'orders';
        $this->type = $type;

        // do logic
        // ...

        return $this;
    }

    public function invoices($type)
    {
        $this->method = 'invoices';
        $this->type = $type;

        // do logic
        // ...

        return $this;
    }
}

$amazon = new Amazon();

echo $amazon->orders('New')->get();
echo $amazon->invoices('New')->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

As orders and invoices are set methods, I would suggest to do as follows:

```
public function get(array $elements)
{
    $result = [];
    foreach($elements as $element) {
        $result[$element] = $this->$element;
    }

    return $result;
}
```

So, you can call get method as:

```
$amazon = new Amazon();
$amazon->orders('New')->invoices('New')->get(['orders', 'invoices']);
```

** You need to validate the element's availability within the `get` method.